# Apache mod_rewrite - why friendly URL doesn't works with static files?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, freebsd

My configuration to use friendly URL works fine when the destination is a php script, like this:

```
RewriteRule ^products/([a-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /prod.php?id=$2&name=$1 [NC]
```

But, when I use a static file, like below, as destination, don't works:

```
RewriteRule ^\/css\/\_version\_([1-9]+)\_([0-9])\/(.*)$ /stat/css/$3    [NC]
```

The configuration above only works when I put a redirection flag, like this:

```
RewriteRule ^\/css\/\_version\_([1-9]+)\_([0-9])\/(.*)$ /stat/css/$3    [R]
```

The destination "/stat/css/*.css" exists. When i use a "Alias" configuration it works too. But, I've to use mod_rewrite to do this.

No error logs (debug mode) are colected about it. Only 404 at access logs.

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try (untested)

```
RewriteRule ^css/_version_([1-9]+)_([0-9]\/(.*)$ /stat/css/$3
```

Differences from your example:

- No leading slash. This is needed in a VHost definition, but shouldn't be included in a `.htaccess` file, for example. Your first (working) example doesn't include this.
- Less escaping. It doesn't seem necessary, and makes the expression more legible.